# Thread structure in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got few questions about threads in Java. Here is the code:

TestingThread class:

```
public class TestingThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    volatile boolean pause = true;
    String msg;

    public TestingThread() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Testing thread");
    }


    public void run() {
        while (pause) {
            //wait
        }

        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public boolean isPause() {
        return pause;
    }

    public void initMsg() {
        msg = "Thread death";
    }

    public void setPause(boolean pause) {
        this.pause = pause;
    }

    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }

}
```

And main thread class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestingThread testingThread = new TestingThread();
        testingThread.start();
        testingThread.initMsg();
        testingThread.setPause(false);


    }
}
```

Question list:

1. Should `t` be `volatile`?
2. Should `msg` be `volatile`?
3. Should `setPause()` be `synchronized?`
4. Is this a good  example of good thread structure?

Comment: 1) No. 2) No. 3) No. 4) No. --- I think you should work through some tutorials about threading in Java.

Comment: 1) No 2) YES 3) No 4) Opinion based

Comment: @Tony - 2 is *Yes*.. I insist you read the basics of threading as I think 4 is *No*

Comment: Argh! You are all right. `msg` must be volatile as it indeed is accessed from two different threads (the same with `pause`).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You were actually right, even if you weren't aware of it :) Details in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**> Should msg be volatile?**

Yes.  Does it have to be in this example, No.  But I urge you to use it anyway as the codes correctness becomes much clearer ;)  Please note that I am assuming that we are discussing Java 5 or later, before then volatile was broken anyway.

The tricky part to understand is why this example can get away without msg being declared as volatile.

Consider this order part of main().

```
    testingThread.start();    // starts the other thread

    testingThread.initMsg();  // the other thread may or may not be in the 
                              // while loop by now msg may or may not be 
                              // visible to the testingThread yet
                              // the important thing to note is that either way
                              // testingThread cannot leave its while loop yet

    testingThread.setPause(false);   // after this volatile, all data earlier 
                                     // will be visible to other threads.  
                                     // Thus even though msg was not declared 
                                     // volatile it will piggy back the pauses
                                     // use of volatile; as described [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) 

                                     // and now the testingThread can leave 
                                     // its while loop
```

So if we now consider the testingThread

```
    while (pause) {   // pause is volatile, so it will see the change as soon 
                      // as it is made
        //wait
    }

    System.out.println(msg);  // this line cannot be reached until the value 
                              // of pause has been set to false by the main 
                              // method.  Which under the post Java5
                              // semantics will guarantee that msg will 
                              // have been updated too.
```

**> Should t be volatile?**

It does not matter, but I would suggest making it private final.

**> Should setPause() be synchronized?**

Before Java 5, then yes.  After Java 5 reading a volatile has the same memory barrier as entering a synchronized block.  And writing to a volatile has the same memory barrier as at the end of a synchronized block.  Thus unless you need the scoping of a synchronized block, which in this case you do not then you are fine with volatile.

The changes to volatile in Java 5 are documented by the author of the change [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile).

Answer (score 4):

You have hit quite a subtlety with your question number 2.

In your *very specific* case, you:

1. first write `msg` from the main thread;
2. then write the volatile `pause` from the main thread;
3. then read the volatile `pause` from the child thread;
4. then read `msg` from the child thread.

Therefore you have transitively established a *happens-before* relationship between the write and the read of `msg`. Therefore `msg` itself *does not have to be volatile*.

In real-life code, however, you should avoid depending on such subtle behavior: better overapply `volatile` and sleep calmly.

Here are some relevant quotes from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

Note that, in my list of actions,

- 1 comes before 2 in program order;
- same for 3 and 4;
- 2 *synchronizes-with* 3.

As for your other questions,

- ad 1: `t` doesn't have to be volatile because it's written to prior to thread creation and never mutated later. Starting a thread induces a *happens-before* on its own;
- ad 3: `setPause` does not have to be synchronized because all it does is set the volatile var.

Comment: Well explained, and as you said in one very specific path.   One knit pick though, as explained [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) the happens-before relationship that you described does not necessarily exist with msg.  Look at the table that explains when a volatile can be reordered with a non volatile access.  A volatile load cannot be reordered with a normal load or store, but a normal load store can be reordered with a volatile load.  Ichh this can be so confusing, which is why it is best to make it volatile.

Comment: @ChrisK You have referenced the compiler writers' cookbook; I am drawing from the official Java Language Specification. Even though they will in the end amount to the same conclusion, it is not as obvious when you start from the implementation side.

Comment: volatile is not only to ensure happens-before relationships, it also guatantees that the variable is not cached in different places in systems with more than one procesor. If you don't make msg volatile, it runs the risk of each thread having its own copy of msg i. e. it is possible that the main thread modifies msg and the the other one never "sees" the change. As you can see, multithreading is not an easy topic and is not just about happens-before relationships

Comment: @ChrisK But anyway, the relevant sequences are: normal store, then volatile store; and volatile load, then normal load. Check out the table again and you'll see No in both cases.

Comment: @morgano I think you have a misunderstanding of what *happens-before* is about. Ensuring *happens-before* is *all it takes* for your progrem to be correctly synchronized. That includes any CPU cache concerns. A volatile read/write has many more consequences than just that particular value being visible.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson and I think you are bit confused with ensuring happens-before, the fact that "pause" is volatile doesn't affect "msg" at all, it is still eligible for caching

Comment: @morgano Have you actually studied the Java Memory model in any detail? What you state is in a direct contradiction with it.

Comment: If nothing else, this conversation demonstrates that this topic is not easy and is often misunderstood  :)

Comment: Is this a fair summary, 1) one can get away without making a shared field volatile if there is another memory barrier on the code path that will cause the same effect, and 2) rellying on that without explicit documentation in the code and having a strong need for it is not a good idea?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes I have, actually I'm working on a project for which I had to study the JVM spec. Can you explain the contradiction in which according to you I'm falling?

Comment: @morgano If you read the JMM, you'll find out that the *sufficient condition* for a program to be correctly synchronized is that all inter-thread actions are committed with a *happens-before* between them. And each pair of the four actions mentioned in this answer indeed has a *happens-before* between them.

Comment: @morgano I would say that you are confusing levels of description: there is no mention of "CPU caches" in the JLS (except maybe in the *discussion* inserts). Anything can be "eligible for caching" as long as the observable effects of *happens-before* rules are maintained.

Comment: Here is a question for you guys.  In the Main class, is the compiler allowed to reorder testingThread.initMsg() and testingThread.setPause(false)?

Comment: @morgano, your use of the word cache is misleading.  It is more about when the cpu has to make sure that the data is to become visible to other cpus.  Intel chips do this by writing to the CPU cache.  Without a memory barrier being there, then the cpu is allowed to keep the changes in a register.  Which is what I think you meant by saying cache. It is a subtle distinction though.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson happens-before restrictions are just observed for the variable "pause", the issue is not about happens-before, its about "msg" being eligible for caching

Comment: @ChrisK for you to be clear what I mean by "cache": every thread can have its own local cache. _volatile_ guarantees that the variable is read from main memory and not from the thread's local cache

Comment: @morgano Have you read my quote of the JLS which I have added to the answer? Clearly, *happens-before* is about *any and all* inter-thread actions, not just those involving a volatile variable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you say that the JVM says: "...sufficient condition for a program to be correctly synchronized..." you have a problem there: programs are not synchronized, memory regions are the ones that need to be synchronized

Comment: @morgano Now it is crystal-clear that you either have not actually read the JMM, or are trolling at this point. [Quote:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) `A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races.`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not trolling, and sincerely trying to get to the facts, that sentence you're getting from there doesn't confirm nor deny anything about "msg" being "volatile"

Comment: William F. Jameson explained it well earlier when he said: 'But anyway, the relevant sequences are: normal store, then volatile store; and volatile load, then normal load.' That is correct and would work in this scenario.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson neither the JVM nor the compiler will guarantee that "mgs" won't be cached, they are simply not that "intelligent" having a JVM with that capacity of analysis would be too resource-consuming. You only have that happens-before guarantees with "pause"

Comment: Kind of an aside, what CPUs have a 'thread cache' (as used in this sense, I don't think that storing thread state when scheduling or registers count)?  I am familiar with the concept as a higher level mental model, but not as one that has actually been implemented in hardware.

Comment: BTW, please upvote the question, it has been demonstratred in this already looong discution that it is worth more score than the current one

Comment: @morgano I already have.  And despite it being a little heated in parts, I have enjoyed this conversation.  Thank you.

Comment: @morgano There is no other way to put it but "you are wrong." I have specifically quoted the sentence from the JLS which makes `msg` receive a happens-before arrow (the one mentioning *program order*). Additionally, ChrisK has even linked to a *compiler cookbook* which explains what the JLS requirements boil down to for the compiler writer.

Comment: @ChrisK Each CPU core has its local cache; however all Intel products guarantee cache consistency. On the other hand, I hear that ARM processors do not and requier explicit memory barrier instructions.

Comment: @William F. Jameson, that is interesting; I have not thought of the first level cache as a thread cache before.  I always forget the detail of which cache level is visible between cores, and sockets.  So from what you have said then the first level is visible only to a single core, even if there are other cores on the same socket?  But even then the cpu does not control when that is propagated down to the other levels and main memory.. or does it? Please correct me :)

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson in that case let me extend your same childish conclusion to you: "you are wrong": making volatile the var pause only affect accions (writes and reads) for "pause", the var "msg" is totally unaffected

Comment: @morgano As opposed to your statement, I have backed mine with not one, but two arguments, one of which is the authoritative reference of the JLS. You are not wrong according to me, but according to the JLS.

Comment: @ChrisK My understanding is that Intel's CPUs guarantee cache coherence and that the preclude the observation of out-of-order writes. Even lower-level details of how specifically they achieve that are not known to me.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson oh God, I thought we were going to finish... anyway, let apply fast-track to it: Can you please specify which statement you are citing from the JLS and where exactly it is in the doc? (e. g. 17.4.5)

Comment: @morgano I have already done that in my "you are wrong" comment above:  it is the sentence mentioning *program order* which I have quoted (and linked to) in my answer.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson Ok then, I'll say this in a less polite way: you're taking out of context those statements, such statements ARE PART OF THE DEFINITION OF HAPPENS-BEFORE, that part of the JLS (the definition) DOESN'T EVEN MENTION THE VOLATILE. Now, let me cite another part of that same document (also in section 17.4.5): _A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read OF THAT FIELD._ let me explain this once again: you use "volatile" for pause, then ONLY SUBSECUENT READS FOR "PAUSE" are affected

Comment: @morgano Have you also considered that if `hb(a, b)` and `hb(b, c)` then `hb(a, c)`? You have one stipulation which enforces `hb(1 ,2)` (in my list of actions), then another one which enforces `hb(2, 3)`. Together they also imply `hb(1, 3)`. Anyway, if you are really here to sincerely reach true understanding, I am sure you'll work it out on your own with time.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson you're again playing with the definition of happens-before, you need to demonstrate that there is a happens-before relationship between "msg" and "pause" being volatile. No I don't need to work it out, I've already been dealing with Java threads for 13 years and I know what I'm talking about. See? you've made me feel old now... I'll (finally) stop here... mate, after this heated discution and if you were in the same town as me I'd invite you a beer just to show that there are not resentments...

Comment: just one more comment for those patient (and insane) people who have read up to this point: go to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) (part 17.4.5) read the definition of happens-before and then the rest of the part, you'll need to read it more than once

Comment: @morgano Please don't take this as further oil on the fire, I sincerely urge you to reconsider your knowledge. The semantics of `volatile` which you imply are more-or-less congruent with the Java Language Specification, 2nd Edition. They have been completely rewritten for the 3rd edition (relevant to Java 1.5). The "new" rules mean that it is safe to publish an object graph over a volatile variable, and the receiving thread will see *all* the state at least as up-to-date as at the time of the volatile write. Most of the lock-free concurrency helpers in `java.util.concurrent` depend on this.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson that would be true if "msg" and "pause" were being modified/read in the same logical sequence, something like `msg='hello world';` followed by `pause=true;` (as in the helpers in `java.util.concurrent` you mentioned) in this code they are written/read at different times, the only part were they "converge" (inside the run method) is not enough to guarantee any consistency of msg unless you declare msg also volatile

Comment: @morgano I am arguing exclusively for OP's specific case, and I state that loud and clear. This question is, after all, about the specific case specified by the code. I do also explain that, if interpreted more generally, then I would not recommend relying on this behavior except in very well-defined and strictly constrained situations. An example of such a situation is lock-free publishing of objects.

Answer (score 1):

1&2
Volatile can be treated something like as "synchronization on variable",though the manner is different, but the result is alike, to make sure it is read-consistent.

3.
I feel it does not need to, since this.pause = pause should be an atomic statement.

4.
It is a bad example to do any  while (true) {do nothing}, which will result in busy waiting, if you put Thread.sleep inside, which may help just a little bit. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

One of a more appropriate way to do something like "wait until being awaken" is using the monitor object(Object in java is a monitor object), or using condition object  along with a lock to do so. You may need to refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

Also, I don't think it is good idea either, that you have a local filed of thread inside your custom Runnable . Please refer to Seelenvirtuose 's comment.

Comment: The busy waiting mechanism is not the worst design flaw here. In my opinion a worse issue is the local field of type `Thread`. This `Runnable` object hosts its own thread variable with which it is started. This is against the idea of having runnables, which could be started with threads, executor service, ot whatever.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose but Schildt used the same approach.  http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7345.f09/handouts/s02.chap11.Threads.schildt.pdf

Comment: @Tony I do not know who Schildt is. But still, this is a real design flaw and not recommended.